# Disabling default popup on long press for Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have found many solutions on the web, none have worked. I am using the jquery "taphold" method to bring up an overlay menu, but I also bring up the default context menu consisting of "Open, Save link, Copy link URL, Select text. How can I stop this menu from coming up?

My code bringing up overlay.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {   
        $('.recordlongpress').bind('taphold', function(e) 
             $('#popupPanel').popup("open");
        });
    });
```

A few options I have tried is adding in these lines.

```
 $('a').live("contextmenu",function(){
        return false;   
 });

 $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false
 e.preventDefault();
```

I have tried those options in many forms in addition to many longer options I found and manipulating CSS.

I have a droid razr max that I am testing on and starting to wonder if the problem is possibly with the new "Jelly Bean" update. Thank you for taking the time to read this. I appreciate any help.